# Debugging electron application

Tags: electron

Coming from web development background, I am learning application development with Electron.

With the basic code I made a honest mistake of using `submenu` instead of `subMenu`, I would have expected an error somewhere but the file menu was not clickable at all.

As this is my side/hobby project didn't spend a lot of time to fix it. Next day noticed and fixed this.

I would like to understand on how to debug these kind of issues properly, my code was:

```
// mainWindow.loadURL('URL');
// also tried opening chrome dev tools
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

// create menu template
const mainMenuTemplate = [
    {
        label: "File",
        subMenu: [
            {
                label: "Add Item"
            }
        ]
    }
];

// Build menu from template
const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
// insert menu
Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
```

What I had tried is to open dev tools `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();`, even with this there was no error on console.

Please share some thoughts.

---

Added: Source code of my [`main.js`](https://github.com/forcetrekker/electronshoppinglist/blob/master/main.js) from github repo.

Comment: Electron is just a `nodejs` so you can debugging it as any `nodejs` application

Comment: Hi @TienDuong, thanks for your reply. Could you please add more details or mind adding an answer. :)

Comment: Electron is one main process and a bunch of renderer processes. Renderer processes can be debugged using chrome's dev tools. For debugging the main process I suggest you take a look at [this](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process-vscode) and [this](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging).